# Change the style of the region display selector in oracle apex

Tags: html, css, oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to change the selected region style in the display selector. So, instead of showing a horizontal line under the selected region, I need it to have a background color like a button. and also a hover color for unselected regions
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply give that region a class. For this example, I used `.processed` for *order processed*. To remove your underline you can use `text-decoration: none;` and exchange it with these styles for the hover effect.

```css
.processed {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.processed:hover {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="processed" type="button">
Order Processed
</button>
```

Comment: I add the css code in the page css inline. But I dont know what to do next with this code:

<button class="processed" type="button">
Order Processed
</button>

I dont know where to add it. more over this code: 
text-decoration: none;
it didnt work with me

Comment: @alaaaljuhanii  you will have to provide me w/ more of your code to implement this into your application.